# How can I insert a line break in an astro prop?

Tags: astrojs

I have some components with astro props to insert different HTML strings. How is it possible to insert a line break (eg. for a heading) in an astro prop?

Example:
I have in the component:

```
---
const { image, name, professionalTitle } = Astro.props;
---
<div class="c-person__name">
 {name}
</div>
```

and in the reference:

```
<Person
   image="images/image-1.jpg"
   name="Some Titel <br> should go her"  <!-- line break should go in this line -->
   professionalTitle="Some text"
/>
```

When I put an `<br>`-Tag inside, it will not render.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Astro will escape all inserted text by default, to insert HTML directly without escaping you can use the [`set:html` directive](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#sethtml):

```
---
const { image, name, professionalTitle } = Astro.props;
---
<div class="c-person__name" set:html={name}></div>
```

**Side Note**

You can also use [`set:html`](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#sethtml) on a [`<Fragment>`](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/astro-syntax/#fragments--multiple-elements):

```
---
const { image, name, professionalTitle } = Astro.props;
---
<div class="c-person__name">
  <Fragment set:html={name}/>
</div>
```

This can be useful if you do not want to wrap your [`set:html`](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#sethtml) content with an element